# Enable pop on screen in React Native

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to enable pop on screen?

I am using **@react-native-firebase/messaging** to send notifications, however, the notification banner is not displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about foreground messages, then they won't be displayed out of the box:
[image]

Easiest way to show foreground messaged (user being in application) would be to use another library. One solution might be to use [react-native-push-notification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification)